# Firefox JSON "not well formed" errror on valid JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm receiving the following error message in Firefox:

```
Error: not well-formed
Source File: http://school/courses.booking.add.php?1287657494723
Line: 1, Column: 1
Source Code:
{"type":"error","message":"You have already booked this course."}
```

As you can see, the output is valid JSON (it's created by PHP's `json_encode()` function). And it's served with the `application/json` MIME type. I thought the error might be something to do with the parsing:

```
eval: function(json) {
    return eval('(' + json + ')');
}
```

But even if I don't parse the string, and simply alert the returned JSON response, the error still shows up.

Related Question: ["not well-formed" error in Firefox when loading JSON file with XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677902/not-well-formed-error-in-firefox-when-loading-json-file-with-xmlhttprequest). His solution was to fix the MIME type. Mine's already accurate, so it must be something else.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using any beta version of FF4 + FireBug? I had some weird problems with those...

Comment: FF3.6.11 + FireBug. I was using the error collecting in the web developer toolbar for this, though. I should probably use FireBug more than I currently do.

Comment: If you don't pull the data from the API, instead reading it from a variable `var myJSONObject = {"type":"error","message":"You have already booked this course."}` and then try to `eval(myJSONObject)` does it still give you the same error?

Comment: If I read from an object without evaling it works: `var ret = {"type":"error","message":"You have already booked this course."};`. If I write it as a text string and eval it, it works: `var ret = '{"type":"error","message":"You have already booked this course."}'; ret = ajax.eval(ret);`.

Comment: It actually works perfectly in Firefox and every other browser I've tested. So I can safely ignore the error messages. Still, it would be nice to know what's causing them.

Comment: @Yuval. I also had some weird effect in FF4. Finaly I found a difference between FF3.6 and FF4. The "tab" are not accepted in the last version of FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue using OpenJS's jxs. What was causing the error, in this case, was this conditional in the `load` property (line 33 in version 3.01.A):

```
//XML Format need this for some Mozilla Browsers
if (http.overrideMimeType) http.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
```

It made the browser always expect for XML. That can be easily fixed by this:

```
// XML Format needs this for some Mozilla Browsers
if (format.charAt(0) === "x" && http.overrideMimeType) http.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
```

Since it now makes a comparison of `format`, the code should also have its place changed and should be put after

```
format = format.toLowerCase();
```

Which is currently at line 38. So, the code goes from:

```
32 //XML Format need this for some Mozilla Browsers
33 if (http.overrideMimeType) http.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
34
35 if(!method) method = "GET";//Default method is GET
36 if(!format) format = "text";//Default return type is 'text'
37 if(!opt) opt = {};
38 format = format.toLowerCase();
39 method = method.toUpperCase();
```

To:

```
32 if(!method) method = "GET";//Default method is GET
33 if(!format) format = "text";//Default return type is 'text'
34 if(!opt) opt = {};
35 format = format.toLowerCase();
36 method = method.toUpperCase();
37
38 //XML Format need this for some Mozilla Browsers
39 if (format.charAt(0) === "x" && http.overrideMimeType) http.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the javascript debugger in the Web Developer Toolbar simply expects all Ajax responses to be XML, regardless of the MIME type. Anything else will produce a "not well formed" error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with previous versions of FireFox + FireBug where there existed newlines in front of/after the JSON formatted content. Make sure you clear your output stream before outputting JSON responses on the server side.

JSP example:

```
out.clear(); out.println(json);
```

Comment: That's not it. There's no whitespace at all.