# Getting "not well-formed" in FF error when reading JSON from a local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mime-types

I'm working on a project on my computer and I'm getting "not well-formed" error when trying to read a json object from a file located on my machine.

It happens on Firefox. In Chrome, I'm getting "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file...".

I've tried changing the Mime-type to application/json but in vain.

Could you please help?

---

#### My code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'json/local_json_file.json',
    dataType: 'json',  //or application/json
    type: 'get',
    cache:'false',
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).each(function(index,value) {
            //some code
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the JSON file content?

Comment: AJAX generally can't be used to read from local files.

Comment: Find it here --> https://jsfiddle.net/95fktyg8/

Comment: So what can I use to read local files instead?

Comment: Are you able to read the file if you use `dataType: 'text'`?

Comment: Have you installed a local webserver, or are you loading the website using `file://` schema?

Comment: I've tried but it doens't work.

Comment: Actually, not being able to read local files is a Chrome-specific restriction, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541949/problems-with-jquery-getjson-using-local-files-in-chrome for workarounds.

Comment: I'm loading the web page using file://

Comment: why not add `error: function(e){ console.log(e); }` to your ajax call to see if you can discern more information?

Comment: So in that case what @Barmar wrote is probably the answer for this problem. Install a [http server](https://httpd.apache.org/) and it should work

Comment: it's a test, I cannot use a web server. That's the problem. :/

Comment: This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986629/firefox-json-not-well-formed-errror-on-valid-json?rq=1 It seems like it's a spurious error in the FF debugger.

Comment: So apprently there's no way to overcome this. Chrome doesn't work at all, it doens't pull the json data. At least Firefox does it.

Answer (score 0):

if this is a local file, you should be using [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) It is still asynchronous.

```
$.getJSON("json/local_json_file.json", function(json) {
     //do stuff to the json object here
});
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax` with `dataType: 'json'`. They both end up in the same jQuery code to perform the AJAX request.

Comment: I've used it but got the same problem.

Comment: alright makes sense! I'll leave the answer up for the sake of future readers, your comment is helpful