# Not well formed error when adding geojson object in leaflet map locally

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mime, mapbox, geojson

I am trying to add dummy markers of german companies in Leaflet map using separate geoJSON file, but each time Mozilla returns a non well formed error.

I have tried the solutions proposed in this topic concerning MIME error: ["not well-formed" error in Firefox when loading JSON file with XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677902/not-well-formed-error-in-firefox-when-loading-json-file-with-xmlhttprequest)

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/firefox-error-on-valid-local-json-load-not-well-formed

But nothing changed. There are a lot of topic about server problems but I'm still in local. I didn't found other people using leaflet and geojson with this problem.

I also tried with a HTML link:

```
  <link rel="points" type= "application/json" href="assets/js/mess/german_company.geojson">
```

And use this link in my js file:

```
//dummy data markers
$.getJSON($('link[rel="points"]').attr("href"), function(data){
  var markers = L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
      layer.addEventListener("click", function(){
      var result = document.getElementById("result");
      result.innerHTML = feature.properties.Company + "<br/>Sales: " + feature.properties.Sales + " €<br/>Margin: " + feature.properties.Margin + " €";
      });
    }}).addTo(map);
```

With this method, the map is displayed with the markers, so it works, but I've still this "not well formed" error and I think this causes error with other plugin I use (leaflet.markercluster works but the markers still appear when I zoom out, markers cannot be hide with leaflet removeLayer function)

Anyone have an idea to solve this "not well formed" error?
Thanks!

Comment: You can try to amend the mimetype using `beforeSend` as [in this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/250245/1377002). It will mean you switching to using `ajax` instead of `getJson`, but this solution works because I've used it myself.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the actual data? It's likely that it's invalid JSON.

Comment: Thanks Andy, it works. I had already switch to ajax call but I only put `dataType: 'json'` With `beforeSend` I have no errors