# jquery ajax request to xml resource yields "not well-formed" error in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, firefox

I know this has been asked many times, but the answers given there did not work for me.

I think I am doing a very common request to fetch an xml resource:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "data.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("main").each(function() {
          alert($(this).attr("val"));
        });
      }
    });
```

The full file can be found [here](http://esel7353.org), and the xml resource [here](http://esel7353.org/data.xml).

When I access this with Firefox 36.0.4, I am greeted by an "hello world" alert as expected, but the javascript console lists the errors:

> http://esel7353.org/ : Unable to run script because scripts are blocked internally.
>
> not well-formed :1:76

In many questions asked here, the content type header in the response was inaccurate, but in my case the server tells firefox, that data.xml is application/xml.

In addition the mimeType option does not help.

I also made an clean FF profile to ensure that this is not somehow cause by plugins, but the error messages persist.

Comment: I get no error at all with FF 36 and chrome 41...

Comment: I've tested it on two computers running on ubuntu and arch linux, and on both I get the same error. I agree that chrome does not report anything.

Comment: and on a vm with win 7 and FF 34, 35, 36 I get the same error.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677902/not-well-formed-error-in-firefox-when-loading-json-file-with-xmlhttprequest and especially this comment : "req.overrideMimeType("application/json"); req.send(null); works". Maybe it will help (replacing json with xml, of course)...

Comment: I read that too, and it works indeed: http://esel7353.org/json.htm, but I wonder what's the problem with xml.

Comment: I can't say if it works better, still have no errors  :o)

Comment: I've tested it with an clean ubuntu 14.04 live dvd, and get the same error. Seems like a bug in ff or ubuntu, which also affects the vm. Thanks @JeremyThille for your replies.

Comment: You forgot to close $(document).ready(function() {. 
The last " }); " is missing.

Comment: possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062247/jquery-call-to-find-function-gives-a-not-well-formed-error-in-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062247/jquery-call-to-find-function-gives-a-not-well-formed-error-in-firefox/) - but since your question is also unanswered I will post it here too.

---

I can't say for sure that it will fix your problem, but I had similar issues with the 'not well-formed' message in firefox. Turns out there is a bug in jQuery 1.11.2 and 1.11.3 - https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1969 - which is fixed upstream.

It's a relatively minor change if you host jquery on your server - see the [github commit](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/commit/50ebe1a43c0842f33ce363259f1a9eed236aca19)

on jquery.1.11.3.js line cca 1197 (in `QSA/matchesSelector` section):

```
 -              "<select id='" + expando + "-\f]' msallowcapture=''>" +
 +              "<select id='" + expando + "-\r\\' msallowcapture=''>" +
```

Hopefully there will be a new release soon.